# Can I get the parent Div tag innerHTML from a child span click event see code

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
  <div class='Myclass'>
     Value I Want, I have already got the span inner html, but I want to add the the value of the div
     <span onclick='Some javascript to get div value'>some html</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please better clarify, I am confused about what you are asking. Adding a little bit more html would also help.

Comment: Sorry my code was cut off, I have a <div> with a few<span> elements

Comment: I was hoping to get the parent inner html of the Div tag, in my click event on the span element

Comment: <div>     <span onclick='my function'> value</span></div>

Comment: Thank you; I am ready to write an answer :D

Comment: ...like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1p2j4em7/

Comment: here is my javafunction: I added the code you sent and it killed my function

Comment: function get_val(val) {
 var b = val.innerHTML;
 var a = b.replace('<b></b>','');
 alert(c);
}

Comment: send from my html is get_val(this); on the span

Comment: I have a <div> then multiple <span> like 60 spans, my data is in a table from My sql, I have Risk and Safe headings that the 60 span reside within, I need the Risk or Safe value, the Risk div has the 60 spans, and the safe div has the 60 other span elements

Comment: I just get an empty alert

Comment: here is the function:

Comment: function get_val(val) {
 var b = val.innerHTML;
 var a = b.replace('<b></b>','');
 var c = val.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim();
 alert(c);
}

Comment: I had looked at that, I may not have captured correctly. Let me play with that. Thank you

Comment: I had a work around but it was not as clean as nice wanted

Answer (score 2):

Tell me if I can improve this answer.

Please thank @JoshCrozier for his jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/1p2j4em7/) which imparted some new information for this answer to be the best it could be.

```js
function getText(elem){
  alert(elem.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim())
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='Myclass'>
    Value I Want, I have already got the span inner html, but I want to add the the value of the div
    <span onclick='getText(this);'>some html</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is a solution that is generic for as many divs as you want.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('Myclass');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].children[0].onclick = function() {
      alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim())
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='Myclass'>
    Value I Want, I have already got the span inner html, but I want to add the the value of the div
    <span onclick='getText(this);'>some html</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: An easier approach would be to grab the `.nodeValue` property of the previous text node.. for instance, `elem.previousSibling.nodeValue.trim()`, then you don't need to remove/append the element - https://jsfiddle.net/1p2j4em7/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I'll have to look at `nodeValue` and `trim();` because I am not familiar with those. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Why did you remove your answer? Your suggestion is actually better than mine and I encourage you to post an answer to this question.

Comment: I never posted an answer, although I did post an example link in the comments. Feel free to put that in your answer, I have enough rep :)

Comment: @JoshCrozier Oh, thought I saw your answer earlier. Why don't you write an answer :)

Comment: Close, I get the whole values of the <span> that exist in the table, I am missing the <div> Risk all the 60 spans </div> RI

Comment: sorry, I need the value Risk form the div that wraps all the span elements

Comment: @dan I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you better explain? Thank you.

Comment: <body>
  <div class='Myclass'>
    Risk
    <span onclick='getText(this);'>some html</span>
  </div>
</body>

Comment: I have 60 span elements in the Risk <div> I also have a mirror of the data in a <div> safe tag, I was hoping to get the Risk of Safe value of the div, I have all the spans between the div, should I have don't the div wrapper differently

Comment: <body>
  <div class='Myclass'>
Risk
    <span onclick='getText(this);'>some html</span>more spans
  </div>
  <div class='Myclass'>
   safe
    <span onclick='getText(this);'>some html</span> more spans
  </div>
</body>

Comment: @dan Do you want me to make a generic algorithm that will do this if you had an *x* amount of this markup? I hope I understand. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: My span elements are dynamic from a MySQL query, the contents change between div tags depending on the query, there are 8 fixed headings in the span, the code provided get the heading first, but the Risk or safe pat is missing from it

Comment: If I have a code window I could show the layout better

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It will now work with an infinite amount of `Myclass` divs.

Comment: Sure, I will have to have a counter in there somewhere to get the X value

Comment: thank you, Just not that confident with Javatext to have this work on the click event of the span, working on it... Thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm not at the extreme level you are at. I simply renamed a table header with the value I needed and used this, replacing the alert to my query string I needed:function get_val(elem) {
 var parent = elem.parentNode.textContent;
 outText = parent.substring(0, 4);
 alert(outText);
}

Comment: @dan Just style the elements the way you would like with CSS.

Comment: @dan Thank you. If my answer worked for you, click the checkmark to accept it as the answer that worked for you. Check this out too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I will have a look, thank you again